# Edit NavBar information based on routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a code with which i am trying to hide a Navbar item when the user click on a specific link. For example, i have a home, profile and shop page, with a Nav bar item of all 3. If the user clicks profile, the profile item should be hidden, if the user click shop, shop should be hidden. How do i go ahead and accomplish that? See my code below

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './pics/KNG.jpg';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';


import Header from './Component/header';
import Landing from './Component/landing';
import Product from './Component/product';
import Menu from './Component/menu';

const loggedIn = true;

class App extends Component {
   render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App"> 

            <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
      />

            <Menu />

            <header className="App-header">
              <br></br>
              <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
              <Header name="KC" loggedIn={loggedIn}/>
              <Route path="/profile" component={Landing} />              
              <Route path="/shop" component={Product} /> 

            </header>

        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Menu component

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'

function Menu(props) {
return (<menuComp>

   <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed ="top">
          <Navbar.Brand href="home">KNG Rental</Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="home">Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="profile">Profile</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="shop">Shop</Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
          <Navbar.Text>
            {props.head}

            </Navbar.Text>
        </Navbar>
   </menuComp>)
}

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have approached this issued in the past by checking `window.location.pathname`.

In each component such as `Home`,`Profile`, and `Shop` I add an `componentDidMount()` lifecycle event with the following function. If they are functional components you will have to change to class components.

Next you will need to add `id` to each link to make it easier to get. Such as

`<Nav.Link id="home-link" href="home">Home</Nav.Link>`

You `componentDidMount()` lifecycle will look like this

```
componentDidMount() {
const pathName = window.location.pathname;
const splittingPathName = pathName.split("/");
const viewName = splittingPathName[1];
const element = document.getElementById(`${viewName}-link`);
element.classList.add("hide");
```

}

In either the css file for each component or menu component or global css file add

```
.hide { display: none }
```

Depending on how you are doing history you might have to do your `componentDidMount()` as follows

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.onpopstate = () => {
      const pathName = window.location.pathname;
      const splittingPathName = pathName.split("/");
      const viewName = splittingPathName[1];
      const element = document.getElementById(`${viewName}-link`);
      element.classList.add("hide");
    };
  }
```